# openapi generator creates inappropriate model due to abstraction

Tags: openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am trying to create a Java client for a DHL api using the openapi generator maven plugin.
The definition of the API as yaml can be found at the following [link](https://developer.dhl.com/sites/default/files/2023-07/parcel-de-shipping-v2_2.yaml)

In the scheme, abstraction occurs twice.
Consignee is oneOf ContactAddress, Locker, PostOffice, POBox
and
Shipper is oneOf Shipper, ShipperReference

My settings of the plugin look like this:

```xml
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <version>6.6.0</version>
    <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/dhlParcelDeShippingScheme/parcel-de-shipping-v2_2.yaml</inputSpec>
          <generatorName>java</generatorName>
          <modelPackage>dhl.parceldeshippingapi.model</modelPackage>
          <apiPackage>dhl.parceldeshippingapi.api</apiPackage>
          
          <configOptions>
            <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
            <booleanGetterPrefix>is</booleanGetterPrefix> 
            <library>native</library>
          </configOptions>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I am getting a model created that uses an "AbstractOpenApiSchema.class". And my "Consignee.class" and "Shipper.class" extends the "AbstractOpenApiSchema.class". The constructors use instance objects.

```java
//...
    public Consignee(ContactAddress o) {
        super("oneOf", Boolean.FALSE);
        setActualInstance(o);
    }

    public Consignee(Locker o) {
        super("oneOf", Boolean.FALSE);
        setActualInstance(o);
    }

    public Consignee(POBox o) {
        super("oneOf", Boolean.FALSE);
        setActualInstance(o);
    }

    public Consignee(PostOffice o) {
        super("oneOf", Boolean.FALSE);
        setActualInstance(o);
    }
//...
```

With the serialization thereby also an **instance** object occurs in shipper and consignee, which must not exist:

```json
{
  "profile": "xyz",
  "shipments": [
    {
      "product": "product",
      "billingNumber": "billingNumber",
      "refNo": "refNo",
      "shipper": {
        "instance": {
          "name1": "name1",
          "addressStreet": "addressStreet",
          "addressHouse": "1",
          "postalCode": "1234",
          "city": "city",
          "country": "DEU"
        },
        "isNullable": false,
        "schemaType": "oneOf"
      },
      "consignee": {
        "instance": {
          "name1": "name1",
          "addressStreet": "addressStreet 2",
          "postalCode": "1234",
          "city": "city",
          "country": "DEU"
        },
        "isNullable": false,
        "schemaType": "oneOf"
      },
      "details": {
        "dim": {
          "uom": "mm",
          "height": 100,
          "length": 200,
          "width": 150
        },
        "weight": {
          "uom": "g",
          "value": 500
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It should look like this:

```json
...
"refNo": "refNo",
"shipper": {
    "name1": "name1",
    "addressStreet": "addressStreet",
    "addressHouse": "1",
    "postalCode": "1234",
    "city": "city",
    "country": "DEU"
},
"consignee": {
    "name1": "name1",
    "addressStreet": "addressStreet",
    "addressHouse": "1",
    "postalCode": "1234",
    "city": "city",
    "country": "DEU"
},
...
```

I also tried to use an implementation via interfaces with
`<useOneOfInterfaces>true</useOneOfInterfaces>` 
Then ContactAddress, Locker, etc. get "impelements Consignee" and "Shipper implements ShipmentShipper". But Consignee and ShipmentShipper are not created as interfaces for their part.

Maybe the polymorphism is translated incorrectly. If this is the case, I'm afraid I don't know what the reason is.

I need to get rid of this instance object. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A solution was to choose a different library in the configOptions of the plugin. Instead of "native" I took "apache-httpclient".